# How do I define my model if I need an auto-incrementing ID but want to check for duplicates on another field?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a class like this. My goal is to update the `last_seen_date` each time a duplicate link is encountered.

I've defined the `id` column, because this will be used as a foreign key into another table. This is auto-incrementing. The true duplicate is the `url`.

```
class Link(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'links'
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    url = Column(String(500), nullable=False, index=True, unique=True)
    last_seen_date = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.datetime.now())
```

I'd like to do an `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, but I don't know how to define the fields to accomplish this. The way I have it now, I can never duplicate because the combination primary key always has an auto-incrementing portion in the ID.

How do I need to change my definition to allow an `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement to work when the `url` is a duplicate, I can change the `last_seen_date`?

Comment: I think you have already got what you wanna.  " allow an `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement to work when the `url` is a duplicate, I can change `the last_seen_date` "

Comment: Maybe I'm confused @LittleQ, i assumed it wasn't working and thus the question. Maybe NewGuy is here to report that it was a success and wanted to share it with us

Comment: why not working?`INSERT INTO table (url,last_seen_date) VALUES (1,2)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE last_seen_date=2;` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Exactly. And by having a unique index on url the insert on duplicate if passed by a mysql programmer and not a sqlalchemy wrapper is going to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `ttt_url` (`url`);
```

ttt_xxx would be the name of the key which i do out of habit. It will allow for insert / on duplicate and you can update the date/timestamp and preserve your original pk

Comment: Don't have have that already defined with the `index=True, unique=True`? Or does this do something different?

Comment: I am talking about at the database level enforcing it and comsuming your insert query that has the on duplicate code embedded in it